# Remove / disable empty groups from expanding

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

How do I remove empty/null groups from being expanded in a report?

I've created a report that may need up to 10 levels of grouping, but quite often the expandable groups won't actually need to go down that far.. for example this group has nulls in every group below it:

[image]

Ideally the above would just be **1.1.2.1. CIS (team)** group with no ability to expand down further because the next group is null. I'd like this effect at any point down the expandable tree where the next group is null.

This is how my report is setup:

[image]

Each group's **Display can be toggled by this report item** property is currently set to the group above it.

I'm using Report Builder 3.0.

Comment: What is the purpose of the grouping hierarchy?  This sounds like something that should be fixed by looking at how you are pulling out your data and applying data-driven groupings based off of that.

Comment: If this is for an organisational hierarchy, you will want to use a `Recursive Parent` group: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2008/10/15/using-analysis-services-parent-child-hierarchies-in-reports/

Comment: Although mine's not for an organisational hierarchy, I think this looks like it could work all the same. I've taken a look at the rdl file referenced in your link and found the recursive parent is set in the row group's properties, in the Advanced section (for anyone else reading). Will let you know how I get on and thanks.

Comment: hmm, couldn't get it to work.. mine just seems to make random sub groupings that don't seems to relate parent/child. not sure what the underlying data this example was based on without having to install the adventure works samples. I suspect my underlying query is to blame. Thanks anyway.

Comment: All you need in your underlying query is an `ID` field and a `ParentID` field and then the `Recursive Parent` will do the rest.  What does your query return?  Are you manually searching for 10 levels of inheritance?

Comment: In my case I'm working with permission group hierarchies rather than org structure. I have a table that defines the child/parent relationships of permission groups, so have written a query that essentially has the `Child_ID` and `Parent_ID` columns from there, but also brings in the the descriptive name of the permissions (both child and parent). So I have `Child_ID`, `Child_Name`, `Parent_ID` and `Parent_Name`. The report table is grouped on `Child_ID`, and the recursive parent is set to `Parent_ID`. I've then set the textbox of the group to display the `Child_Name`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126629/discussion-between-iamdave-and-matt-hall).